# Make EC2 Autoscaling scale-out more quickly for customMetric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I'm setting up an AWS EC2 Autoscaling Group (ASG) and it's using TargetTrackingScaling that is tracking a custom metric. This metric is published by each instance in the ASG every 30 seconds.

It's working fine, but I'd like the scale-out action to happen more quickly. The source of this looks to be due to the ASG Alarm that gets auto generated. To me it looks like it's waiting for at least 3 datapoints over 3 minutes before ringing the alarm.

Is there a way I can configure the ASG/Scaling policy such that the alarm only needs 1 datapoint (or less time) before deciding to ring the alarm? Or if that's not possible, can I create a custom alarm and use that instead of the alarm that the ASG auto generated.